# How do I find one word using regex?

Tags: regex

I am creating a bot which takes a natural language as input. I want for example to find the words "árbol" or "carbón" in the input from the user.

It must be case insensitive and accent insensitive. It must find the words anywhere on the sentence.

Examples:

> arbol - (should detect)
>
> caRbóN (should detect)
>
> Carboooon - (should detect)
>
> ÁRBOL - (should detect)

The issue comes when I want to detect the word in a sentence. The following must not happen:

> Eso es unárbol (should NOT detect)
>
> el arbola - (should NOT detect)

Using regex I have the following:

```
/(á+)rb(o+)l|c(a+)rb(ó+)n|(a+)rb(o+)l|c(a+)rb(o+)n/i
```

I know I have to use `\s` in order to have a space, but when I tried this:

```
/(\s)(á+)rb(o+)l|c(a+)rb(ó+)n|(\s)(a+)rb(o+)l|c(a+)rb(o+)n/i
```

It does not detect the word if I have, for example, just:

> arbol

I will only detect

> un arbol

Lastly, is there an easier way to have all accentuated words considered, instead of just putting both cases?

Comment: Are you looking for `\b` - *Word Boundary* ?

Comment: What is the language/regex library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundary `\b` instead of `\s`, that will also check the first/last character.

> Matches a word boundary. A word boundary matches the position where a word character is not followed or preceded by another word-character. Note that a matched word boundary is not included in the match. In other words, the length of a matched word boundary is zero. (Not to be confused with [\b].)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary

Answer (score 0):

The entire solution for my code is:

```
/\b(á+|a+)rb(o+)l\b|\bc(a+)rb(ó+|o+)n\b/i
```